# register including post fail

Tags: php, registration

I am trying to build a login system with registration etc.
now for the registration i use a form and the method "post". Now it fails in what i think is sending the input trough the post. can you help me fix it? here is the code involved in it:

above !doctype

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email) VALUES ($username, $password, $email)";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    if($result){
        $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
    }
else
  {echo "fail";}
}
?>
```

the form:

```
<div class="register-form">
<?php
if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
    echo $msg;
}
?>
<h1>Registreer</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
<p><label>User Name : </label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>

<p><label>E-Mail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
 <input id="password" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="name@email.com" /></p>

 <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
 <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>

<a class="btn" href="login.php">Login</a>
<input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Registreer" />
</form>

</div>
```

The connect.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sqluser";
$password = "Welkom01!";
$dbname = "users";

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$connection){
die("Database Connection Failed". mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);
if (!$select_db){
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to change your code as per my answer, you need to mark it as an edit underneath your original code. People will visit my answer and stand at downvoting it because of it.

Comment: my bad will do next time

Comment: It's ok, I did a rollback. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**As per your originally posted question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26873836/1) and without marking it as an edit under your newly edited question, should anyone wonder why the answer.

---

Since we're more than likely dealing with strings

```
VALUES ($username, $password, $email)
```

needs to be wrapped inside quotes:

```
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')
```

you also need to pass DB connection to your query `$result = mysqli_query($query);`

**Edit:** (you added your DB connection code after) [**from your original post**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26873836/1)

Since you've not shown what your DB connection is, this would be something like

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

plus, adding `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`

You also have a missing `&` in `if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){` which should read as `if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)){`

---

- However, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer i inserted the connect.php (you helped me with it i believe) in the edit and the quotes in my own html but it is still not working (it is gaining the else out of the first part and no entry in the database). and i will look in to the security. thanks for the tip

Comment: my mistake for the second include i copy'd it twice to here it is only once in my page

Comment: @deboer You're welcome. I've made an additional edit: You also have a missing `&` in `if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){` which should read as `if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)){` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything else.

Comment: @deboer Another thing, it's irrelevant but you have 2x `<input id="password"` for both your Email and password inputs. You can also try changing `type="email"` to `type="text"` in some cases, using `type="email"` doesn't work, I've seen that happen before.

Comment: as it is now its working. i will try type text and change the input id (i didn't know what i was thinking with the id... but thanks for all the patience and help

Comment: @deboer You're welcome. I posted a note under your question as well as an edit in my answer. Your edit should always be marked as an additional edit under your original code (if it's what you tried and did not work) and marked as such, otherwise people will visit my answer and say: *"There's nothing wrong with this, why the answer?"* - Please do a rollback to your original in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @deboer Would you mind if I did a rollback to your original question? This one http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26873836/1 because it will just cause confusion with your edit and my answer.